# phpmyadmin - Out of memory (allocated 1008730112) (tried to allocate 377483264 bytes)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin on a local PC that is not exposed to the Internet, for development purposes only.

I have edited `php.ini` to allow unlimited size files, unlimited processing time, set Memorylimit to 1 GB or unlimited in `config.inc.php` etc'.

Every setting that could help has been tried to no avail.

```
max_execution_time=-1
max_input_time=-1
memory_limit=-1
post_max_size=1000M
default_socket_timeout=-1

$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = '1000M';
```

As you can see from the title.

**Out of memory (allocated 1008730112) (tried to allocate 377483264 bytes)**

I have allocated 1GB of memory and only 377MB was used before the error.

Is there any known solution for this?

Comment: This means that you already used 1GB and it tried to get 377 MB _more_ after that. What on earth are you doing with phpMyAdmin to use all that memory?

Comment: Ah. ok that makes sense now, but still doesn't offer any advice on addressing the issue. Importing an SQL file with about 5 million lines (250MB file size) Seems that it's using more memory than necessary?  When researching this issue I don't see people allocating that much memory even for far larger files.   I just tried it hoping it would work.

Comment: Hm, you should probably import the dump yourself instead of using phpMyAdmin.